# Python 3.0 apply same logic to two lists using a single list comprehension with two for loops

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

Problem:
Make a list comprehension that uses the elements of two different lists, and selects only those elements of each list that are non-negative.
Conditions: **For this you should use two for loops.**

My problem is finding a solution using a single list comprehension containing two for loops.
Alternative answers that do not fulfill conditions are shown below:

A = [-5, 0, 5, 15]

B = [-10, 20, 30]

Attempt 1 - this solution has one for loop outside the list comprehension:

```
for i in B:
    A.append(i)
newList1 = [i for i in A if i >= 0]
```

Attempt 2 - this solution uses two concatenated list comprehensions:

```
newList2 = [i for i in A if i >= 0] + [j for j in B if j >= 0]
```

Attempt 3 - this solution uses one for loop:

```
newList3 = [i for i in A + B if i >= 0]
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Why doesn't attempt 2 work? There are two for loops there.

Comment: Answer calls for only one list comprehension and Attempt 2 has two list comprehensions. All three of my attempts do solve the problem just not under the conditions given

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

A = [-5, 0, 5, 15]
B = [-10, 20, 30]

[ item for outer in zip_longest(A,B, fillvalue=-1) for item in outer if item >= 0 ]
```

Comment: This gives the following incorrect solution: [(0, 20), (0, 30), (5, 20), (5, 30), (15, 20), (15, 30)] . Thank you for responding, though

Comment: Well, it fulfils the specifications: Collect non-negative elements from two lists in a list comprehension using two for-loops. It's not a nice output format, obviously, but I don't see a better way at the moment.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see what you mean, it's not pretty but it does fulfill the specifications. 
Thank you

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that is a short and simple solution. I wonder if there is an alternate solution that does not need to use a module like itertools. In any case, thank you so much for your help and quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [-5, 0, 5, 15]
B = [-10, 20, 30]

new_list = [(x) for x,y in zip((a for a in A if a*-1 < 0),(b for b in B if b*-1 < 0))]+[(y) for x,y in zip((a for a in A if a*-1 < 0),(b for b in B if b*-1 < 0))]

print(new_list)

>>> [5, 15, 20, 30]
```

What I done initially was this:

```
new_list = [(x,y) for x,y in zip((a for a in A if a*-1 < 0),(b for b in B if b*-1 < 0))]
```

But this gave me a list of tuples:

```
[(5, 20), (15, 30)]
```

So what I done was iterate through the tuple twice in the same list comprehension.

Then extracted index[0] from the first list of tuples, and extracted index[1] from the second list of tuples, and then added these together.